# Render fileContent with actual data from listItems

Tags: reactjs, typescript, list, sharepoint, rendering

In this render function, I retrieve the data from a list in SharePoint and render the `fileContent` but the properties didn't get replaced from `listItems`

Here is my code of the render function that I tried:

```js
 public render(): React.ReactElement<ILinkItemsWithReactProps> {
    return (
      <div className={styles.linkItemsWithReact}>
        <ol>
          {this.state.listitems.map((listitem, listitemkey) => {
            console.log(this.state.listitems);
            return (
              <li key={listitemkey}>
                <a>{this.state.fileContent}</a>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I want to render the `fileContent` of a specific template and display the properties of this template from the actual data of `listItems`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are iterating over the `this.state.listitems` yet not using them except as the key prop.

Did you mean to render `listitem.fileContent` or similar in the loop?

Comment: this.state = {
      listitems: [
        {
          Title: "",
          ID: "",
          SoftwareName: "",
          SoftwareVersion: "",
          SoftwareDescription: "",
          SoftwareVendor1: "",
        },
      ],
      fileContent: "",
      isButtonClicked: false,
    }; this is the state

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the value provided by the map callback but instead some other state.

The following code should work if you replace `content` in `listitem.content` with the correct attribute.

Also the second parameter of the callback of [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) is the `index` in the array so I changed that as well.

```js
return (
  <div className={styles.linkItemsWithReact}>
    <ol>
      {this.state.listitems.map((listitem, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <a>{listitem.content}</a> // TODO: replace content with the actual attribute
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ol>
  </div>
);
```